# cfwheels Find Records and Output as JSON Encoded

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I am new to ColdFusion, currently using CFWheels Framework. I have a snippet that send a ajax request from the view using jquery post with two parameters name and time.

```
$(".building").on("blur", function() {
      $.post("index.cfm/audit/building", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
          .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
          });
        });
```

My controller action

```
<cffunction name="building">
        <cfscript>
            categories = model("buildings").findByKey(params.name);

            test = params.name & params.time;
            renderText(test);
        </cfscript>

    </cffunction>
```

My Model

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model">
    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfset table("buildings")>
        <cfset hasMany("rooms")>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I wish to do a simple task as following

1. check if any building by passed name exist in database
2. if so then return the row in json format, like echo json_encode in php
3. else create new record and redirect to another action with params

I am stuck on step 1, and its telling me

```
The value for cfqueryparam cannot be determined
```

What does this mean? Please help, also if anyone can also tell me how to render query data in json form for jquery post to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just sharing the answer.

```
<cffunction name="building">
        <cfscript>
            buidling = model("buildings").findOneByName(params.name);

            if(IsObject(buidling)) {

                //return json format
                renderText(SerializeJSON(buidling));                                

            } else {

                //enter new record
                new_building = model("buildings").new();
                new_building.name = params.name;
                new_building.save();

                //return id json
                renderText(SerializeJSON(new_building));            
            }   
        </cfscript>

    </cffunction>
```